# bootstrap.css and datatable.min.css is conflicting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

bootstrap.css and datatable.min.css is conflicting.pls help.Its gives error object doesnot support cssRules or object.assign property.I have bootstrap.css in layoutview and datatable.min.css in view

Comment: show as the order how you are  loading them?

Answer (score 0):

As per `Datatable` website one can get into this mess easily so the best way  according to them

> That is correct - the two stylesheets should not be used together. Use the DataTables Bootstrap integration stylesheet instead

Comment: <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js"></script>

Comment: var oTable;$(document).ready(function (){'use strict';oTable=$('#peopleList').DataTable({"responsive":true,"ajax":{"url":"api/PMInfoList",contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",dataType:"json","dataSrc": "" },"columns":[{"data":"pName"},{"data":"countryName"},{"data":"stateName" },{"data":"cityName" },{"data":"locationName"}],"columnDefs": [{"render": function(data,type,row){return row["countryName"]+ "," + row["stateName"] + "," + row["cityName"] + "," + row["locationName"];},"targets": 4},{ "visible":false,"targets":[5,6,7]}]});

Comment: yadcf.init(oTable,[{column_number: 0,filter_type: "auto_complete",text_data_delimiter: ","},{ column_number: 1},          {column_number: 3,filter_type: "auto_complete",text_data_delimiter: ","},{column_number: 4,filter_type: "auto_complete",text_data_delimiter: ","}
            
            ]);
        $('.yadcf-filter-wrapper').addClass('input-group');
        $('.yadcf-filter, .yadcf-filter-date', this).addClass('form-control input-sm');
        $('.yadcf-filter-reset-button', this).addClass('btn btn-default btn-sm').wrap('<span class="input-group-btn"></span>');
        });

Comment: above is my files and code.i hv written all this in view.cshtml.i am getting error "object doesnot support property or method assign" (object.assign)

Comment: i have tried with datatable.bootstrap.min.cs but it is also conflicting with bootstrap.cs file

Comment: @Zain Could you please write that code in the question in a correct format  so we can understand what is going on? and sorry for the late reply

Comment: I want to use datatable in mvc application.i am using bootstrap.cs file as well as datatable.yadcf.cs file.on browser sometimes it shows error as "object doesnot support property or method 'assign'" and some times it shows error as "var n=obj.cssRules".when i have further googled it. it showed me that its a browserlink issue.so i have disabled it in visual studio.in microsft edge there is still error but on other browser it is not displaying.

Comment: can u refer some good link for nested grid with paging,sorting,filtering in mvc.Many Thanx

Comment: There are some very good for example I would prefer Jtables created by a turkis fella  one can find them on [Jtables main site](http://www.jtable.org/) and discreption can be found on [Code project website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277576/AJAX-based-CRUD-tables-using-ASP-NET-MVC-and-jTa)

Comment: @Zain please click the links in above given comment